# @ mentions don't always display a user

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

Why is it that when I want to mention in a comment or an answer a user, sometimes it displays the name, and other it just doesn't? I'm not sure if that is supposed to happen? Is it because some of them have a space in their user names? Why?

Comment: Can you give us an example where the user name is not shown?

Comment: The `@` sign has no special meaning in answers, only in comments, and subject to [constraints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931073/dynamodb-vs-mongodb-nosql/18116695?noredirect=1#comment26532141_18116695, for example I'd like to mention @derick

Comment: You mean in your comment to Derick's answer? There the message will always go to the author of the answer. So no @reply is necessary. It would become available (afaik) if another user were to comment on the same post.

Comment: Your question is surprisingly lacking in free hand circles.

Comment: @Gilles can you specify some constraints?

Comment: Just read through the post he linked @Pedro.

Comment: @Bart add a cooment to derick's answer

Comment: So yes, the author of the post will always be notified of the comment. The @reply is not necessary in that case.

Comment: For the linked duplicate [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), see a possible answer to your question in item #10: "If only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment..."`

Comment: ok guys! thanks for the quick support, I totally appreciate that!